# How to add a keyboard shortcut to Firefox Quantum using the CTRL key

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

How do I add an keyboard shortcut to Firefox 57+ (Quantum) using the CTRL-Key? I use Windows 7, and wish to alter the key bindings to add a function not found at [Mozilla's list](http://mzl.la/16NAhwz). I tried the add ons [Saka Key](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/saka-key/), [Shortkeys](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/shortkeys/), and [Vinium-FF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimium-ff/) but they don't allow use of the CTRL key; I also searched for any method involving edits to the config files, to no avail.

I want to use, for example CTRL-X to change to offline mode, which now must be performed with {**MENU**} | **More** | **Work Offine** . With Quantum there's no way to do those steps except by mousing. There might be other things to add in the future, but that's the immediate objective.

Is there an option I didn't notice or is it just not possible? Some posts say shortcuts aren't possible at all but I'm not sure because I found the add ons doing just that.

Comment: Which shortcut do you need? What is it suppose to do?

Comment: Originally I wanted to switch to offline mode but I would also like to know the general answer.

Comment: Please edit the question to indicate what you want to accomplish, what OS you are using, what version of Firefox you are using, and what else you have tried (Saka and Vinium so far)

Comment: I added the inforamtion

Answer (score 0):

**Alt-F** **K** or **Alt** **F** **K**
will do the job with no changes, extensions, or edits.

Tried to create a ***Ctrl-*** based hotkey with [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/), a free, open-source scripting language for Windows. So far, the script isn't working as it should; it stalls after getting to the Files menu. I've tried

```
   ^x::   
   Send !fx  
   Return
```

and

```
   ^x::  
   Send !f  
   Send, {Up 2}  
   Send, {Esc}  
   Return
```

However, since **Ctrl-X** is a standard for cutting text or data which predates Microsoft Office, going back to when IBM's [Common User Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access) and [PC-DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PC_DOS) were Hot Stuff, finding a different keystroke combination [not in common use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts) is *Highly Recommended*.  I know **Ctrl-X** is hotwired into my limbic system, and thinking about using it for something else give me the *Willies*.